# Add further event handler to jquery datepicker month drop-down

Tags: jquery, events, select, datepicker, handler

I've been asked to remove months from the month drop-down on our jQuery datepicker if there are no flights that month.  My initial thinking is, in the **beforeShow** event, to add a change event handler to the **year** drop-down that will go off and call a function called, say, monthHasFlights() for each month in that year (calling it manually the first time the datepicker loads).  I will then remove that month if monthHasFlights() returns false.  **Problem is** ... my handler won't attach.

So, inside the beforeShow event handler I have this:

```
$('.ui-datepicker-year').change(function(){setDropdownMonths()});
```

but the event never attaches, even though I see this line execute in firebug/tools  My understanding of jQuery event binding is that you can assign to the change event as many times as you like and the handlers will fire in the order you create them.. but I guess I've got that wrong?  Is it simply that the drop-down does not yet exist when I try to attach the event handler?  I did try a setTimeout of 100 but my event still doesn't attach. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Post your HTML code where datapicker is used and also JQuery inicialisation code. Best way to create jsfiddle.com example

Comment: The datepicker is attached to a textbox that has css class "datepickerOut", so: `$('.datepickerOut').datepicker(dpOpts);` where dpOpts is a JSON style colelction of options.

Answer (score -1):

Possible issue: you try to change `datepicker` befor it was inicialized.
I suppose, best way to achive your task will be add your function call inside code of inicializing `datapicker`.

Also, .change event will fire when the element on which it's attached will change it's state. I don't see your HTML and JQuery code to say for sure, but possibly, the event just not fire because of this issue.

`$('.ui-datepicker-year')` are you sure there is CLASS, not ID in your HTML for this element?

---

UPDATED:
I have found event in datapicker which can help you:

```
beforeShow      function(input, inst)
```

Can be a function that takes an input field and current datepicker instance and returns an options object to update the datepicker with. It is called just before the datepicker is displayed.
Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the beforeShow event as an init option.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   beforeShow: function(input, inst) { ... }
});
```

So you can use it event whule inicialisation datapicker to call your function which will exclude empty months from the list!

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm seeing the code try to attach the handler  and, in the UI, I click on the select to change the value in the year drop-down so any event should fire.  Could be that the select object has not yet been added to the DOM...?? but surely a setTimeout would address that.

Comment: Yup the rendered html is: `'<select class="ui-datepicker-year"`

Comment: I have found interesting event for datapicker which can help you - look at my updated unswer

Comment: Actually that works.  The year and month drop-downs re-render the calendar, so I can just use the beforeShow (which already has plenty of code in it!) to test for empty months.  Will post results...

Comment: No good... the beforeShow is not fired when I change month or year in the drop-downs.  The calendar re-draws but is not re-initialised from scratch.  So I still need to attach my handler to the onchange of the drop-down.